# Installing miniconda on alpine linux fails

Tags: docker, anaconda, alpine-linux

I have been attempting to install `miniconda` on an Alpine linux docker image. The minimal "working" example of my failure can be reproduced with Docker as follows:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine sh
/ # apk update && apk add ca-certificates wget && update-ca-certificates
/ # wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.3.27-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
/ # sh miniconda.sh -b 
PREFIX=/root/miniconda3
installing: python-3.6.2-h02fb82a_12 ...
/root/miniconda.sh: line 361: /root/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.2-h02fb82a_12/bin/python: not found
```

The file that it looks for is there, though:

```
/ # ls /root/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.2-h02fb82a_12/bin/python
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.2-h02fb82a_12/bin/python
```

I would appreciate some insight on this error. I have little idea of what to try next

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to @VladFrolov, anaconda's python is linked to glibc, which isn't available in alpine. For more details about how he built an alpine image with conda, look at https://github.com/frol/docker-alpine-miniconda3

PS: Looks like @VladFrolov now maintains miniconda3:alpine official image https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/master/miniconda3/alpine/Dockerfile ( Thx for pointing out @rpanai )

Comment: This “glibc workaround” is a very ugly hack that may lead to unexpected behaviour and errors. It’s not and never will be supported by Alpine developers, we strongly discourage from using it. If you want miniconda3 on Alpine, compile it from source and ideally contribute an APKBUILD for it.

Comment: Great to know @JakubJirutka

Comment: @JakubJirutka If the "glibc workaround" is an ugly hack, is there an existing APKBUILD that builds Miniconda using musl-libc? All of the Docker images I've discovered thus far use this same hack of installing glibc as a prerequisite to build Miniconda.

Comment: Alpine developers approve of patches on glibc to build a python package - https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/tree/master/main/python3/

Comment: - https://gist.github.com/dazza-codes/96eefbe03d96b841637775712e84f808

Comment: - https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/merge_requests/4796

Comment: @gerrit I think I clarified your question

Comment: @GabrielMirettiakagmiretti Thanks, I've deleted my comment.

Comment: Hi @GabrielMirettiakagmiretti what about their official image see [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/continuumio/miniconda3/4.8.2-alpine/images/sha256-b9c9f2c7748abdb3291ef2e9b04a8ef3e355f0d7e8030e7a07b8f26c11ed88be?context=explore)

Comment: It looks like miniconda official image offers @VladFrolov image. I could add that to the original respond. Thx

Answer (score 7):

You can add this before running the ./miniconda.sh -b:

```
apk --update add \
bash \
curl \
wget \
ca-certificates \
libstdc++ \
glib \
&& wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-node-bower/master/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
&& curl -L "https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r3/glibc-2.23-r3.apk" -o glibc.apk \
&& apk add glibc.apk \
&& curl -L "https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r3/glibc-bin-2.23-r3.apk" -o glibc-bin.apk \
&& apk add glibc-bin.apk \
&& curl -L "https://github.com/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-i18n-2.25-r0.apk" -o glibc-i18n.apk \
&& apk add --allow-untrusted glibc-i18n.apk \
&& /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
&& /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc/usr/lib \
&& rm -rf glibc*apk /var/cache/apk/*
```

Comment: This is really helpful, as I have a need to install miniconda in a pre-built container (docker in docker). Thanks very much!
I did run into an issue of something like _dl version mismatch when bashing the miniconda.sh. The root cause apparently is due to the difference of python version installed (3.8 pulled in by apk) vs the python used inside the miniconda.sh (3.7). Once I download the miniconda built with python 3.8, then installation went without problem.