# How to avoid error "conda --version: conda not found" in az ml run --submit-script command?

Tags: python, azure, conda, azure-cli, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to run a test script on an existing compute instance of Azure using the Azure Machine Learning extension to the Azure CLI:

```sh
az ml run submit-script test.py --target compute-instance-test --experiment-name test_example --resource-group ex-test-rg
```

I get a Service Error with the following error message:

```
Unable to run conda package manager. AzureML uses conda to provision python\nenvironments from a dependency specification. To manage the python environment\nmanually instead, set userManagedDependencies to True in the python environment\nconfiguration. To use system managed python environments, install conda from:\nhttps://conda.io/miniconda.html
```

But when I connect to the compute instance through the Azure portal and select the default Python kernel, `conda --version` prints 4.5.12. So conda is effectively already installed on the compute instance. This is why I do not understand the error message.

Further information on the azure versions:

```
  "azure-cli": "2.12.1",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.12.1",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {
    "azure-cli-ml": "1.15.0"
  }
```

The image I use is:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:latest
```

Can somebody please explain as to why I am getting this error and help me resolve the error? Thank you!

EDIT: I tried to update the environment in which the `az ml run`-command is run.
Essentially this is my GitLab job. The installation of miniconda is a bit complicated as the azure-cli uses an alpine Linux image (reference: [Installing miniconda on alpine linux fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177538/installing-miniconda-on-alpine-linux-fails)). I replaced some names with ... and cut out some irrelevant pieces of code.

```yaml
test:
  image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:latest'
  script:
    - echo "Download conda"
    - apk --update add bash curl wget ca-certificates libstdc++ glib
    - wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-node-bower/master/sgerrand.rsa.pub
    - curl -L "https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r3/glibc-2.23-r3.apk" -o glibc.apk
    - apk del libc6-compat
    - apk add glibc.apk
    - curl -L "https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.23-r3/glibc-bin-2.23-r3.apk" -o glibc-bin.apk 
    - apk add glibc-bin.apk 
    - curl -L "https://github.com/andyshinn/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.25-r0/glibc-i18n-2.25-r0.apk" -o glibc-i18n.apk
    - apk add --allow-untrusted glibc-i18n.apk 
    - /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 
    - /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc/usr/lib
    - rm -rf glibc*apk /var/cache/apk/*
    - echo "yes" | curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o miniconda.sh
    - echo "Install conda"
    - (echo -e "\n"; echo "yes"; echo -e "\n"; echo "yes") | bash -bfp miniconda.sh
    - echo "Installing Azure Machine Learning Extension"
    - az extension add -n azure-cli-ml
    - echo "Azure Login"
    - az login
    - az account set --subscription ...
    - az configure --defaults group=...
    - az ml folder attach -w ... 
    - az ml run submit-script test.py --target ... --experiment-name hello_world --resource-group ...
```

Comment: to clarify, are you trying to use a Docker container as the environment in which you use the CLI to submit a job to a compute instance? My gut tells me the error message isn't about the compute instance's environment, but rather the environment in which you are submitting the run. Perhaps try the [AzureML base docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azureml-base)?

Comment: @AndersSwanson Thank you very much for your reply. I tried to edit the question I hope this clarifies my issue a little bit. So, in essence I tried to do that, but it still did not work. Maybe it is something with the conda path.

Comment: So where does the installer install Conda, and does it add something to your `.bash_profile` (or `.profile`, or `.bashrc`, or ...)?

Comment: (As an aside, `(echo -e "\n"; echo "yes"; echo -e "\n"; echo "yes")` is probably better written `printf '%s\n' '' 'yes' '' 'yes'`.)

Comment: @Anders Swanson Yes indeed, it has proven to be better to install the azure cli on the azureml base image than to install conda on the azure cli image. This works now.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, you were right, somehow conda did not get installed properly, although the .bashrc was indeed modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to pass the `--workspace-name` argument to be able to run it on Azure's compute target and not on the local compute target:

```sh
az ml run submit-script test.py --target compute-instance-test --experiment-name test_example --resource-group ex-test-rg --workspace-name test-ws
```

Comment: @vizhur Your answer is correct as well of course, but I wanted to use the already installed conda environment of the compute target and not execute locally. This is why I accepted my own answer, but marked yours as helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need conda in your base image for container based environment. You can extend the base image by installing conda using base_dockerfile instead of base_image
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.dockersection?view=azure-ml-py
or, which if that works for you, use one of the AzureML base docker images.

If you do not need any python dependencies on top your base image you can set user_managed_dependencies to True and base image will be used as is and no additional dependencies will be installed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.environment.pythonsection?view=azure-ml-py

Comment: AzureML docker base image seems to be the best variant, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
runconfig.environment.python.user_managed_dependencies = True
```

That should solve the issue